# How to associate file types with my android app using Kendo UI Mobile / Cordova / PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, file-association, kendo-mobile

An android app I'm writing using Kendo UI Mobile (based on Cordova and PhoneGap) creates files of its own type (extension), and needs to be able to respond when a user tries to access those files.  How can I accomplish this using Kendo UI and/or Icenium Extension for Visual Studio?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Can you elaborate on "creates files of its own type" ? , you mean it will change extensions of .html , .css and .js to something else?

Comment: No, what I mean is that it will create files of a new type that hasn't existed before.  The app needs to be associated with this new type.

Comment: What is that new type?

Comment: Let's say it's "*.abc"; I just need to know how to associate that extension with the my app.

Comment: You don't have to associate those custom generated files with your app. Use File API from PhoneGap (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) and read/write files.  Those files will be on ur device and can be accessed by your app.

Comment: I know I don't have to associate them to read and write to them.  But I want users of this application to be able to click on one of these files to load my app. So if user A creates a file named foo.abc, they can send it to user B, who will then click on it, causing his instance of my app to load and process that foo.abc file.

Comment: Have you been able to make any progress, i am trying to do the same